# Is UndoManager necessary in the CoreDataBooks sample?

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I have been working on a first application for some time based on the CoreDataBooks sample.  I notice that if I delete all of the UndoManager code, the sample still seems to function normally. I do not care about the shake event, so is this something I can safely delete in a basic table-oriented application (similar to Contacts)? I have spent time with the documentation and on the web, and I do not see how I would use this functionality. Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSManagedObjectContext on ADC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) is pretty clear on this topic

> You can set the undo manager to nil to disable undo support. This provides a performance benefit if you do not want to support undo for a particular context, for example in a large import process—see Core Data Programming Guide.

If you don't need undo support disable it by setting undoManager nil in your context (or do not set it at all)

Comment: Thanks. I found additional information for this event in the iOS Introduction to Undo Architecture document. Your answer confirms that I can safely delete all the code related to UndoManager, and the only effect on the application will be the loss of Undo when the Shake event is called. Also, I did not realize that the Shake event was set by default, which explains my puzzlement when I tried to understand how undo was called in the application. Makes sense now.

Comment: @jon Wow, thanks for pointing that out; I had the same puzzlement.  I wonder how many users are aware that a shake is sometimes undo.  And in this app rather useless as edits are already undone with Cancel.